# Angularjs ajax return not consistent

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a problem with Angularjs (v1.2.14) using $http post, the returned value from the ajax call is not consistent in view. That means the code actually works, but sometimes when I reload the page ( Ctrl + F5), the data doesn't show up ( like an empty obj ), but when I try to reload the page, data will either shows up or not ( like 50-50% chance )

Here's a bit of my code:

```
myGuitarApp.service('songService', ['$http','$q', function( $http, $q ){

this.list = function(){

    return $http
    .post("getSongs.php") // return all songs from my DB in json
    .success( function( data ){
        console.log("1: ajax done");
        })
    .error( function(){
        console.log("error");
        });
}
}])

myGuitarApp.controller('returnAllSongs', function( $scope, $http, songService){

songService.list().then(
    function( data ){
        console.log( data );
        $scope.songs = data.data;
    }, function( data ){
        console.log("not success");
});
});
```

I've read up on some articles about using $q or deferred object on situation like this, but still not lucky, the same problem still happens .

**UPDATE 1:**
I did try with $q method but the returned data still shows up randomly ( empty obj or full data ). Checking in the console log, I found out the line "return promise" always appears before the "ajax done". Is this a problem or something ?

```
this.list2 = function(){
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http
    .post("getSongs.php")
    .success( function( data ){
        console.log("1: ajax done");
        defer.resolve(data);
        })
    .error( function(){
        console.log("error");
        defer.reject();
        });
    console.log("return promise");
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: @andrbmgi actually I just post the update part to show that I've tried the $q method but still doesn't work. I still keep the current code with `return $http.post("getSongs.php")` . Thanks

Comment: `return promise` appears before `ajax done` because of the asynchronicity of this code. This is expected and correct. The post request is issued and the program just continues performing the `return promise` output and more, all before the post request is finished. Once the server responded one of the functions you defined in `success` and `error` is called.

Comment: I transformed my first, now deleted comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $http service already returns a promise, so if your songService does not handle the data in between there is no need to wrap it inside of another promise. Keep in mind though that **the server might send some unexpected message** with a non-error http code, in that case the promise would be fulfilled. I added debug output to the console. Check what the server returns.

```
myGuitarApp.service('songService', ['$http', '$q',
  function($http, $q) {

    this.list = function() {

      return $http.post("getSongs.php");

    }

  }
]);

myGuitarApp.controller('returnAllSongs', ['$scope', '$http', 'songService', function($scope, $http, songService) {

  songService.list().then(
    function(data) {
      console.log("success");
      console.log(data);
      $scope.songs = data.data;
    }, function(data) {
      console.log("not success");
      console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

You might want to keep the post request wrapped to perform a check on success. Say the server sometimes returns something unexpected, you could do something like:

```
myGuitarApp.service('songService', ['$http', '$q',
  function($http, $q) {
    this.list = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.post("getSongs.php").success( function(response) {
        if ( response.indexOf("loading") > -1 ) { // loading would be the unexpected response, you can turn that around and search for something known in the expected response
          deferred.reject(response);
        } else {
          deferred.resolve(response);
        }
      }).error( function(response) {
        deferred.reject(response);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
]);
```

Alternatively you could as well perform that test in the controller. The question where it fits best is something you have to consider.

Comment: thanks, one thing I forgot to mention that this happened when I was testing on my local pc, but I when tried it on my laptop or on a hosting it seems like the problem has gone. Tried hitting ctrl + f5 to reload the page like 15-20 times and it always return full data... that's weird

Answer (score 0):

in the success function do return the data

```
 .success( function( data ){
    console.log("1: ajax done");
    return data;
    })
```

you also need to return a promise

```
this.get = function(from, to){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var url = 'user/activities?from='+from+'&to='+to;
        $http.get(url).success(function(data, status) {
            // Some extra manipulation on data if you want...
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            deferred.reject(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

so in your case that would be
        var deferred = $q.defer();

```
return $http
.post("getSongs.php") // return all songs from my DB in json
.success( function( data ){
    console.log("1: ajax done");
            deferred.resolve(data);
    })
.error( function(){
    console.log("error");
            deferred.reject();
    });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't solve the problem, I've tried it with or without that "return data", the data still shows up randomly

Comment: I've tried your method of using deferred, but the same problem still happens :(

Comment: Console log data on http success.check if that's always coming, else it might be a server issue. But you would need q service hence don't remove that code